# How do I numerically compute the time propagation of a many body system using Exact Diagonalization?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, simulations, many-body, time-evolution

So let's say I have a half filled fermionic system. I managed to get my Hamiltonian by using a numerical basis for every Fock state. I can get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of my Hamiltonian. Now I want to see how my system evolves over time but I can't figure out how I do that with those eigenvalues and eigenvectors i.e. the time evolution using ED (exact diagonalization).

Comment: What state do you want to time evolve? The ground state?

Comment: It’s an model with nearest neighbor hopping amplitude, tunneling term and disordered potentials. I want to time evolve a initial condition say 4 sites and 2 fermions at the first two sites.

Comment: Decompose that state onto the eigenvectors you get from ED, then evolve each component using the good'ol exponential with energy eigenvalue and time.